# Matching part of a multivalued field to my setString function

Tags: sql

I am trying to select payment plans for a specific term from my database.  The problem is that my pay_plan field is multivalued, and is set up like this: UTAD*00000*2010SP.  I want to match up the specific terms like so:

```
stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT person FROM schema.payments WHERE pay_plan = ?"); 

stmt.setString(1, term);
```

Is there anyway to only match the characters after the final *, or is there any other way to go about this?

Comment: If I am understanding you right, it is Oracle 11g.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WHERE
   pay_plan LIKE '%*%*' + @MySearchValue;
```

This means you'll match only the last bit and assume you always have `abc*123*wanted`

Note: an index will be ignored because of the leading `%` so you'll have to accept poor performance as a consequence of un-normalised data

Comment: What do you mean by @MySearchValue?  I am trying                 WHERE pay_plan LIKE '%*%*' + ?

Comment: You may need to wrap ? in quotes

Answer (score 0):

Try [last index of *](http://david-burger.blogspot.com/2009/02/sql-last-index-of-lastindexof.html) and then do a substring in the query.